# how to fix 1120: Access of undefined property main in initializing starling section?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs6, starling-framework, feathers-ui

i am new in actionscript3, i have a problem with my code that i refer to [Designing for a multi-device, multi-resolution world](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/designing-multidevice-multiresolution.html) and i stuck at initializing starling.
the syntax is good but found error when i test my project by ctrl+enter.
here is my code

```
this.stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
this.stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;

import feathers.system.DeviceCapabilities;

DeviceCapabilities.dpi = 265;
DeviceCapabilities.screenPixelWidth = 480;
DeviceCapabilities.screenPixelHeight = 800;

import starling.core.Starling;
import flash.events.Event;

var starling:Starling;

this.loaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaderInfoComplete);
function loaderInfoComplete(e:Event):void
{

    starling=new Starling(Main, this.stage);
    starling.start();
}
```

Comment: in `starling=new Starling(Main, this.stage);`
the `Main` class is valid??

Comment: i don't really know what is the `Main`

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is from the initiation of Starling:
`starling=new Starling(Main, this.stage);`

It needs a class rather than `Main` to startup.

What you need to do is insert a new symbol with `class: screen` and `extends starling.display.Sprite`. as Shown below:
[image]

then modify your code as `starling=new Starling(screen, this.stage);`

PS: it seems you are using flash cs6 to develop starling. It is quite difficult to handle. Suggest Flash Develop or Flash Builder instead.

Comment: how can i get that window?

Comment: i am new in flash developing and i want to try flash builder but i need the frame by frame animation.@user3711105

Comment: insert -> insert symbol

Comment: have a check, how to use frame animation with flash builder:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KAYBFUn1XU0

Comment: is it easier to build any apps in flash builder that can fit in any android screen?

Comment: sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

When you create Starling, you need to pass in a class for Starling to instantiate as its "root" container. In your code, you're asking Starling to use a class named `Main` here:

```
starling=new Starling(Main, this.stage);
```

Do you have a file in your project named `Main.as`? If not, then you need to create one. Here's some simple example code that you could try to add to `Main.as`:

```
package
{
    import starling.display.Sprite;

    public class Main extends Sprite
    {
        public function Main()
        {
            super();

            var quad:Quad = new Quad(100, 100, 0xff000);
            addChild(quad);
        }
    }
}
```